# How to set default HttpClient in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, httpclient, sentry

I want to set a default HttpClient for [Sentry](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry_flutter) and use it in all requests

The program is old and completely written and used in many `HTTP` classes

I know I can use `SentryHttpClient`, but to do this I need to make changes everywhere that are written. Instead, I want to create an `http.Client()` and set the required ones.

Comment: The typical way to override the default [`HttpClient` from `dart.io`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html) (AKA `io.HttpClient`) is to use [`HttpOverrides`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpOverrides-class.html).  However, looking at `SentryHttpClient`, it is a [`Client` (from `package:http`)](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client-class.html) (AKA `http.Client`), which is not the same thing. I'm not sure offhand how to override the default `http.Client`.  I think https://github.com/dart-lang/http/pull/697 would help you.